# python filter and discard elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, filter

I have the following function, _discard_func_2, that takes 2 args:lab_lis is a (often a long ) list of objects and new_lab_lis is a ( short) list of objects. An (simple) example of what lab_lis and new_lab_lis contain is objects of this class

```
Class Label():
   def __init__(node, loadf, cost):
       self.node = node
       self.cost = cost
       self.loadf = loadf
```

`mark` and `mark_new` are two lists initialized with zeros and have the same length as lab_lis and new_lab_lis respectively. The function iterates over new_lab_lis and lab_lis and checks whether an object (lab_1 or lab_2) is dominated and changes 0 to 1 in the corresponding index of mark or mark_new:

```
 def _discard_func_2(self, lab_lis, new_lab_lis):
    dom = self.dominates
    mark = [0] * len(lab_lis)
    mark_new = [0] * len(new_lab_lis)
    for ind, (lab_2, m_2) in enumerate(zip(new_lab_lis, mark_new)):
        for e, (lab_1, m_1) in enumerate(zip(lab_lis, mark)):
            if m_1:
                continue
            else:
                co = dom(lab_2, lab_1)
                if co:
                    mark[e] = 1
                    continue
                elif co is False:
                    mark_new[ind] = 1
                    break
    return mark, mark_new
```

dominates(lab_2, lab_1) function returns True if  lab_1 is dominated and False if lab_2 is dominated and None if none is dominated. if an object is dominated then, it is not compared again against the other objects and will be ignored afterwards:

```
def dis_dominated(ULj, TLj, new_lab_lis):
   union = ULj + TLj
   len_u = len(ULj)
   dominated_indices, new_dom_indices = self._discard_func_2(union, new_lab_lis)
   return deque([lab for lab, m in zip(ULj + new_lab_lis, dominated_indices[:len_u] + new_dom_indices) if not m]), deque([lab for lab, m in zip(TLj, dominated_indices[len_u:]) if not m])
```

the function dis_dominated takes 3 deques , and return 2 deques.

It calls _discard_func_2 to get the indices of the objects in union and new_lab_lis that should be ignored, and returns the objects in ULj + new_lab_lis that should not be discarded and the objects in TLj that should not be discarded.

Any idea on how to speed up these two functions? They arer called a lot of times  and seem to be the bottleneck of my code

Comment: It would be really helpfull to have a working example (what is in the varialbes?)

Comment: @Okapi575 please check my edits

Comment: Still, the provided code does not seem a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)